# Convert RGB from string to number and back

Tags: python, colors

I hold RGB values as a 9 character string. For various reasons I need to convert this into an integer, then back again to a 9 character string.

```
String1 = '000004000'   # almost black
Num = int(String1)
print Num
>>> 2048
String2 = ????(Num)
print String2
>>> 000004000
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

```
String2 = "%09d"%Num
```

I guess... Im not sure how `int('000004000')` is equal to 2048 ..

[edit] after some detective work I now realize its octal numbers ...

```
oct(2048).zfill(9)
```

of coarse this will be problematic if the leftmost number is anything other than zero... if it is you can do something like

```
String2 = oct(2048).zfill(9) if len(oct(2048)) <= 9 else oct(2048)[:9]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you need:

```
import socket
import struct

def to_integer(text):
    return struct.unpack('>I', socket.inet_aton('0.{}.{}.{}'.format(text[:3], text[3:6], text[6:])))[0]

def to_string(value):
    return '{:03d}{:03d}{:03d}'.format((value >> 16) & 255, (value >> 8) & 255, value & 255, )

print to_integer('000000001')
print to_integer('000004000')

print to_string(1)
print to_string(1024)
```

This would display the following:

```
1
1024
000000001
000004000
```

The strings you have are in the form `[0-255][0-255][0-255]`. `to_integer` makes use of a library function to convert an IP address into a number (which happens to have the same format, except there are 4 parts).

Comment: Great, glad it solved your problem! Don't forget to click the grey tick to accept a solution when you're done.

Comment: I spoke too soon. the above routine does not work in all cases.here are some examples that do NOT work: "191191191" or "255255008. I get the error message "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 8: '255255008'

Comment: The above routine will not work in some cases: "255255008" "191191191"

Comment: By the way. Where do I find the "grey tick" ?

Comment: Try now, I see now what you have is 3 lots of values in the range 000 to 255. (The grey tick should be to the left of the answer, under the up down vote buttons)